# Solve $(x-2)^6-19(x-2)^3=216$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve the following equation:

$(x-2)^6-19(x-2)^3=216$

If $(x-2)^3=y$, I got equations I can't solve: $(x-2)^3=8+2\sqrt{70}$ and $(x-2)^3=8-2\sqrt{70}$. How to get it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

$$y=(x-2)^3\implies y^2-19y=216$$

Either use [Middle term factor](https://www.aplustopper.com/factorization-by-splitting-middle-term/) $$\implies(y-27)(y+8)=0$$

Or use Sridhara'fs [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sridhara) to find $y=3^3$ or $(-2)^3$

Comment: Thank you! My fault! Instead of $-19y$ I wrote $-16y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$x \left( x-5 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-x+7 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+
12 \right) 
=0$$